# Why would a language spoken by humans entirely lack bilabials?

Tags: language

Bilabials are nearly universal consonants within human speech. However, why would a naturally evolved language spoken by humans lack bilabials entirely?

Comment: Oh so many. My favourite is: Because it's a naturally evolved language in a non human race, and humans adopted it when they become allies. Eg when humanity joins a galactic federation led by a non humanoid race and realises the economic benefits of adopting the universal language. (perhaps more info is needed?)

Comment: @Ash, the only speakers of the language and its predecessors are human.

Comment: There is no rule which says that all languages have to use all the phonemes which can be made by humans. For example, why does English lack (1) front rounded vowels (such as German *ö* and *ü* or French *eu* and *u*, (2) pharyngeal fricatives such as /ʕ/ (which give Arabic its distinctive sound), (3) palatalized consonants (ubiquitous in Russian), (4) geminated consonants (as in Greek, in Latin and in Italian), (4) words ending in /a/ or /e/, (5) native words starting with /ʒ/ or /kn/? Moreover, lo and behold, there do exist [languages which lack bilabials](https://wals.info/chapter/18).

Comment: P.S. For other examples of common sounds missing from a language: ancient Greek does not have /f/ or /v/ or /j/ (the sound of the letter *y* in the word *yes*) or /w/; Latin doesn't have /v/; French and German don't have /dʒ/ (the sound made by the letter *j* in English); and the most common reconstruction of Proto-Indo-European has extremely few (and suspect) words containg the voiced bilabial stop /b/.

Comment: There are [languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whistled_language) which lack *consonants*. And, in a sense, vowels, for that matter. Why *shouldn't* a language lack bilabials?

Comment: This might be a better fit for https://conlang.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Matthew There are *codes* which lack consonants. "Whistle languages" are universally secondary registers of otherwise-normal language, with consonants. There are none which exist as independent languages on their own.

Comment: @AlexP I thought English has geminated consonants (albeit not mid-root-word), e.g. in "bookkeeper"?

Comment: @BalinKingOfMoriaReinstateCMs: That's not a geminate, those are two individual k's; there's no difference (in pronunciation) between a bookkeeper and a book keeper. That is, English is perfectly fine with a word ending in a consonant being followed by a word starting with the same consonant, and the two copies of the consonant are pronounced separately; as in "thin nation", "dim mind" and so on. By consequence, two copies of the same consonant can end up in the middle of a compound world. But the two copies remain separated in pronunciation; a geminate would be a long or emphatic consonant.

Comment: @AlexP Thanks for the clarification—it seems that Wikipedia led me astray :-(

Comment: What are the criteria for the best answer to this question? There are currently 9 unique answers each with plausible explanations. VTC:Opinion.

Comment: @LoganR.Kearsley there are languages that do lack consonants though. They're not whistled for the reason you give, but sign languages don't have a meaningful consonant/vowel distinction in their phonologies

Comment: A culture that cuts off the lips of infants shortly after birth... for some sort of misguided reason.  Other [major modification of the soft tissue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lip_plate) around the mouth could do just as well.

Comment: Because a hundred years ago the king had a lip defect (congenital, or perhaps a battle wound) and couldn't pronounce any of those sounds. The courtiers started imitating the way the king pronounced words, then the wealthy merchants imitated the courtiers, and so on. When it became common, it became a point of national pride: the language of Ool has a refined and delicate pronunciation, not like the barbaric tongue of the adjoining kingdom of Oul.  And then it became a shibboleth: if you pronounced those consonants, people would suspect you were a foreign spy from Oul…

Comment: @AlexP: What does "remain separated in pronunciation" mean? There isn't really an articulatory gesture in _thin nation_ that distinguishes the two nasals. Also, since word-final plosives are often unreleased, it's actually very difficult to find evidence for an articulatory separation even in words like _bookkeeper_. The better argument against geminates as English phonemes is the complete lack of minimal pairs, and the fact that they can potentially only occur on morphological boundaries ([where they do appear to exist](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0095447017300372))

Comment: @Schmuddi Recently, I came across https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/english-today/article/abs/gemination-in-english/F8D0B31A54322769536447E4C2A835E5, for more (potential) evidence of gemination in English.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

When I was a kid one of the game we played with my friends when we were in the sea was to talk underwater and have the other understand what we were saying.

If we were wearing a scuba mask and the mouthpiece for breathing, pronouncing bilabial consonants would be almost impossible, due to the mouthpiece preventing it from happening: papa or mama would have sounded both as a haha.

Imagine a language that starts and develops in a human community where its members spend a lot of time using a mouthpiece: consonants which cannot be pronounced will necessarily fall out of usage.

Answer (score 26):

#### Because they're heavily addicted to nicotine.

Your society learnt to fortify and roll tobacco into cigarettes before they developed a formal language. As grunts started to become standardised, they were being made by humans with cigarettes between their lips.

The desire to avoid cutting off that sweet sweet nicotine mean that sounds made by joining the lips were difficult to do, thus bilabials require extra work than other sounds, and are thus not considered practical for inclusion in the language.

As words are imported into the language after contact with other communities, they're localised by softening all bilabials (ie "paper" -> "hay-her"), as no-one wants to give up the cigarette to accurate pronounce that new word.

Comment: quite conveniently "cigarette" has no bilabials in it

Comment: neither does "tohacco". Or "harijuana" for that matter.

Answer (score 17):

There is absolutely no reason why a language must have bilabials. In fact, several terrestrial languages lack bilabials altogether, including [Oneida](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oneida_language) and [Wichita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wichita_language). No special excuse is necessary.

**EDIT:** @JirkaHanika in the comments suggests a connection between labrets and lack of labials (Jakobson 1941 (transl. 1968) p48, Rood 1975 p317). Though I know of cases where bilabials occur even with labrets (e.g. Kayapo), it could well be the case that such lip operations are a prerequisite to the lack of labials.

Comment: +1 Approximately 0.7% of the world's languages lack [bilabial consonants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilabial_consonant) altogether, including Tlingit, Chipewyan, Oneida, and Wichita.

Comment: @Fred The percentage sounds about right, but note that WALS can be an inaccurate resource; e.g. their source for Eyak lists the bilabial /m/ as a phoneme.

Comment: This answer could be improved by an explanation how wearing of labrets by both men and women speaking Iroquois languages made bilabial plosive articulation essentially impossible.  The correlation between the historic wearing of labrets and the lack of bilabial plosives is striking.  Of course, the anatomical and historical situation on *other* planets may be rather different than here.

Comment: @JirkaHanika I’ve never heard of such a correlation between labrets and lack of bilabials. Do you have a source for this claim?

Comment: @bradrn - Yes, this is known for a long time.  (Jakobson, Roman. 1941 (transl. 1968). Child Language, Aphasia and Phonological Universals.  De Gruyter Mouton).  Re Wichita, I think I've seen it [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/412858).  But of course it is just a correlation, specific to a single world.  As such, it doesn't contradict your frame challenge answer.  Feel free to ask on [this](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/) or [this](https://languages.codidact.com/) site separately if you are genuinely interested further.

Comment: @JirkaHanika Thanks for the sources; I have added this to my answer.

Comment: @bradrn - Looks good to me.  BTW among Kayapo, only men wear lip plates, women and children don't.  (In some other tribes that do have labial plosives, only women undergo other kinds of lip modification - but men don't.)  In our world, it seems the prerequisite to the lack of bilabials could be labrets worn *by both men and women*, and all cases known to me are from North America.

Comment: For clarity: all cases of absent labials are from NA.  Not all cases of lip modification by both genders.  But then it probably matters what the customary method of lip modification is, and I'm sure there are some random factors at play as well.

Comment: @JirkaHanika I did not know that about Kayapo; in that case I suspect you are right in your speculation. (And interestingly, your sources mention that in African cases it is woman who wear the plates — and indeed this corresponds to a lack of bilabials, but only in women’s speech.) At this point I am willing to postulate that the distribution of labret-wearing + areal factors is sufficient to explain the observed distribution of lack of bilabials, but it would be hard to know for sure without a more comprehensive survey of the phenomenon.

Comment: it's worth noting that the wearing of labrets need not be current. In the absence of contact with bilabial-having languages, it could take several centuries after labrets stopped being worn by all adults for bilabials to arise again (likely out of labiovelars or clusters involving a /w/). Even with contact with bilabial-having languages, and the introduction of bilabial phonemes through loanwords, most (all?) Iroquoian languages have yet to evolve any bilabials within their native vocabulary

Comment: @bradrn phoible lists m as marginal in Eyak. From the discussion on WALS it appears that it's an allophone of /w/ before nasal vowels. Depending on whether you're interested in phonemes or phones that may affect whether you think it should count

Answer (score 10):

It happened that the local [whistled language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whistled_language) variant became very useful for some reason (perhaps geography very similar to Canary Islands, spanning the whole continent) and it was ubiquitous in the society for such a long time that it started to influence the spoken language. The whistled variant might have disappeared later on, leaving only traces in rather unusual phonology of the language - heavily tonal language, no stops, few vowels, no consonant clusters, open syllables etc...

Comment: My language is non-tonal and has a rather standard phonology with the exception of bilabials.

Answer (score 8):

A long history of facial decoration that interferes with or obscures bilabials -- for example, piercing of the tongue and upper and/or lower lips. It need not even be universal; if such decoration is a sign of status, then only low-status individuals would be able to make the sounds, thus they would be considered low class and looked down upon, and heavily discriminated against. The higher status people forcibly control the evolution of language.

You can achieve the same effect without physical ornamentation. The ruling class is inbred and develops a heritable speech impediment that interferes with the production of bilabials. Pretty soon, bilabials start to be regarded as a form of mockery, punishable by death.

Comment: piercing of the tongue would surely affect coronal consonants, not labial ones. Only lip piercings would interfere with production of labial consonants

Comment: Are you challenging my knowledge of what "bilabial" means, my hard won knowledge that I wrested from the jealous clutches of Google, immediately after reading this question? How dare you!

Answer (score 4):

Populations stop using some sounds over time, which is why it seems that no single naturally evolved language has all the sounds that humans can do. English, Chinese and Korean lack the hard R sounds of romance languages, almost all romance languages lack the 'v' sound from Spanish, Japanese has no L and so on. Arabic has an 'a' sound that non-native speakers have a hell of a time to pronounce and Russian has a very funny sound that I can only approximate the pronunciation of if I pretend to be stabbed. But the piece of the cake goes to Portuguese 'ão', no non-native speaker will ever be able to pronounce that correctly to save their lives, even native speakers of Spanish!

So if some people don't like or have no use for bilabials, over millennia their languages will drop that sound. [There is a study which suggests that Eyak and Oneida have no bilabials at all](https://wals.info/chapter/18):

> As already noted, Eyak and Oneida are the two languages classed as having neither bilabials nor nasals.

Having never had contact native speakers, I read this with a grain of salt; [The Wikipedia article for Eyak](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eyak_language) mentions a labial 'b' sound. Might be like the Spanish 'uve' - or not, for all I know. Still, I believe that such languages could develop naturally in any world inhabited by humans.

Comment: ‘Could develop naturally’, not ‘would’. There is nothing to indicate that such a language _must_ develop, and only two languages out of over seven thousand indicates that it’s a reasonably rare occurrence. On a side note, the Swedish ‘sj’ sound is another fun example of a language-specific sound (only Swedish and a couple of little-spoken German dialects have it).

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn I think you're right - could is more accurate than would here. I'm editing.

Comment: The Wikipedia article for Eyak *also* mentions that /b/ and /m/ only occur in loanwords. The native vocabulary inherited from Na-Dene lacks them entirely.

Comment: Being a native Russian speaker, I'm now intrigued what that "very funny sound" is...

Comment: @ruslan it's the sound of the letter 'bl' (sorry I don"t know hpw to get it here in proper cyrilics).

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "hard R sound", as English has a couple different "R sounds": can you clarify? Doesn't affect the answer, mind.

Comment: @elemtilas check any Portuguese, Spanish or Italian word with one R between two vowels. English does not have that sound.

Comment: @TheSquare-CubeLaw -- What's the IPA for that sound?

Comment: @elemtilas 122. I see in Wikipedia that English has it in some dialects only: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_dental,_alveolar_and_postalveolar_trills

Answer (score 1):

An extreme real-world example of a natural language lacking many of the sounds other languages have is the Nama language of Namibia, which has only eleven non-click consonants, including glottal stop, plus some allophones. (These do include some bilabials.)

Mundanely, bilabials became allophones of other sounds and disappeared, similar to how English has the fricatives F and V instead of the bilabial fricatives in other languages, and sometimes uses a labiodental nasal as an allophone of M or N (as I do in the words *symphony* or *sin*), but replacing the bilabials more comprehensively.

A more colorful explanation (which might at least be a folk etymology) is that some king or hero had a speech disorder that prevented them from fully articulating their lips, and others imitated their accent.  Or bilabials became the equivalent of the raspberry, and taboo.  Or, some prudes thought that puckering their lips looked like having an orgasm, so proper young ladies would say [p̺ɯ], never [bu].

Or those might all be just-so stories people tell to explain it. How many of the reasons for any of our language shifts in the ancient past do we actually remember? That’s just how they talk, and we can only make educated guesses why.

Comment: ‘An extreme real-world example of a natural language with none of the common sounds of other languages is the click languages of Africa.’ — This is false. Khoisan languages have plenty of common sounds: /b/, /d̪/, /ɡ/, /t̪/, /k/, /ʔ/…

Comment: @bradrn Thank you for the correction.

Answer (score -1):

A "naturally evolved" [sic] language could lack bilabials or any other morphological change, because "natural evolution" can only simplify, merge or drop sounds altogether. The direct application of intelligence is required to create more complex cohesive structures.

A universally observed phenomenon of all language families is that inflexional morphology has simplified over time. The history of the IE family overwhelmingly illustrates this, and sometimes in very short time scales (about 200 years each for the Great Vowel and High German shifts).

Theoretical reconstruction of proto Indo European suggests that there were three genders, eight noun cases and three verbal aspects; far more complex than European languages today.

To illustrate this, note that **synthetic** languages use word-endings to indicate meaning, rather than the word order that is essential to derive correct meaning in **analytic** languages like modern English. Consider the sentence "the boy loves the girl", where changing the order of the nouns would reverse the meaning entirely, since there are no inflexions to identify subject and object.

As languages become more analytic over time, the need for word endings to derive meaning reduces, and inflexional morphology becomes less and less significant, vacuuming the *natural* motivation for *humans* to bother with the complexity. Ethnic mixing, where strangers struggle with language concepts, may promote the degradation of the native language and accelerate the *natural* simplification process.

Anyone who has tried to speak a foreign language (or hears a foreigner speak their own language) knows that the word endings are the most easily confused or omitted elements of the words. The earliest form of English, known as Old English or Anglo-Saxon (c. AD 450-1150), was highly inflected, with three genders and several cases. Within the approximate period AD 800-1000, there were many Scandinavian invasions into England, and for a while most of NE England was ruled by Danes and this area was known as the "Danelaw". The language spoken by the invaders is known as Old Norse (from which modern Danish, Swedish, etc. have descended), and was similar to Old English in many ways, being also a Germanic language. Because of the mixing of these peoples whose languages had similarities, the inflexions of Old English were worn down.

To put it simply "natural evolution" deconstructs, simplifies, and degrades. It cannot build complexity or structure. The wonder is not why languages would lack bilabials at all, rather we should wonder how they have been retained and who originated them in the first place.

- Baugh, A.C., A History of the English Language, Routledge and Kegan, London, 1959
- Barber, C., The English Language: A Historical Introduction, Cambridge University Press, Cambridge, 1993
- Millward, C., A Biography of the English Language, Holt, Rinehart and Winston, New York, 1988
- Waterman, J.T., A History of the German Language, University of Washington Press, Seattle, 1966
- Collinge, N.E., The Laws of Indo-European, John Benjamins Publishing Company, Amsterdam/Philadelphia, 1985
- Weekley, E., The English Language, Andre Deutsch, London, 1952
- et al.

Comment: To my understanding, this is an oversimplification of current knowledge on linguistics. Certainly simplification is *common* among natural languages. But so is the opposite; Finnish, for example, has 15 noun cases while its ancestor Proto-Uralic is believed to have had only 6. And modern English has more than ten contrasting vowel sounds (possibly as many as 15, depending on how you count) while Proto-Indo-European had 4 (counting vowel length). "Ethnic mixing" is also known to complexify as well as simplify: see hybrid languages like Michif, which combines aspects of French and Cree grammar.

Comment: In fact, it is trivially easy to see that natural evolution of languages must have gone from simple to very complex at least once.

Comment: I think your assumptions about simplification in language are just a touch exaggerated. Yes, English verbal morphology has become very "simple", but in contrast,  English verbs have become very complex in their lexical construction and also in their tense-aspect construction. Phrasal verbs, bizarre constructions, all of these happen without any actual application of intelligence.

Comment: In other words, language evolves corporately and in a non-directed fashion. Take this sentence from an actual Twitter twat: *I usually stay longer, and if I had would have gone to see Caroline's one-woman show, which sounds fascinating.* This verb has become so complex that is now completely impossible to determine what it really means.

Comment: '"natural evolution" can only simplify, merge or drop sounds altogether' is incorrect. Sounds can split, resulting in new phonemes. Likewise morphology can complexify, and this is attested in Indo-European, even in well-known languages. The Romance future & conditional aren't inherited directly from Latin but are a new synthetic structure derived from an analytic one (originally the infinitive followed by an inflected form of habeo, with the present tense giving the new future, and the imperfect giving the conditional)

Comment: the fact that, when controlling for things like size of speaker population, ancient languages look typologically indistinguishable from modern ones also suggests that whatever simplification processes occur must be exactly balanced (on average) by complexification processes. In morphology, we see that grammaticalisation balances out phonological erosion of existing paradigms, and new sound changes introduce new irregularities and paradigms. Sometimes it's suggested that this forms a cycle but this is not generally accepted. Instead it seems to be more of a dynamic equilibrium

Comment: @elemtilas, random uncontrolled changes are hardly specific complexity! It's just nonsense. Intelligence isn't contained within the "sentence", you need to apply intelligence to try to understand what the person might have been trying to say. This lack of basic comprehension of the difference between chaos and complexity needs to be called out.

Comment: @Tristan, that seems like a novel explanation to me. Are there any peer-reviewed texts that support your theory? As far as I'm aware there has always been a constant struggle to explain the observed simplification of language within all the distinct groups, and in fact the presence of those distinct groups also itself posing a challenge to anyone wanting to demonstrate a mechanism whereby all these languages could have separately arisen.

Comment: @NeilG Dixon (1998) proposed the cycle, but more nuanced approaches are discussed by van Gelderen (2011) in the Linguistic Cycle: Language Change and the Language Faculty. Grammaticalisation is a well described process though, and the 2009 OUP Language Complexity as an Evolving Variable takes it for granted that the consensus is that complexity is constant across history (but then argues against that in favour of variation about that constant, rather than strictly not varying)

Comment: within Indo-European, we can see that PIE is only reconstructed as having two declensions (thematic and athematic), but the various old Indo-European languages generally have several more. Likewise the verbs seem to have had just two conjugations (thematic and athematic), with just three sets of endings (both active & middle) for each eventive verb (primary, secondary, and imperative), with stative verbs only having one set of endings. The entire tense structure and system of conjugations in the daughters is innovated from various derivational forms